# How can I insert array literal into Snowflake table explicitely?

Tags: arrays, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to insert an array literal into table:

```
INSERT INTO tableA
VALUES 
(1, ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b1']),
(2, []);
```

But I get error:
SQL compilation error: Invalid expression [ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(‘a1’, ‘a2’, ‘a3’, ‘a4’, ‘b1’)] in VALUES clause.

I also tried:

```
INSERT INTO tableA
VALUES 
(1, ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b1')),
(2, ARRAY_CONSTRUCT());
```

But it produces the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays and VALUES don't go along.
You need to do it without the VALUES clause.

This will work:

```
insert into my_table_with_array_column 
SELECT 1,  ['a1','a2','a3','a4','b1']
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, [];
```

And this:

```
insert into my_table_with_array_column 
SELECT 3, ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('a1','b1')
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, ARRAY_CONSTRUCT();
```